# Extracting High & Low 16 bit Words from a 32 bit number

Tags: c, mask

I have the following code that " functions " in that I can write a 32 bit counter value and place it in the High and Low words of the 32 bit register in a dsPic.  I am using MPLAB X IDE and the XC16 compiler.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned long My_Number;      // 32 bit
  unsigned int High_Word;       // 16 bit 
  unsigned int Low_Word;        // 16 bit    
    
  My_Number = 0x6000C000;       // Decimal 1610661888

  High_Word = (My_Number & (0x1FFFF << 16)) >> (16);     // Returns 6000
 
  Low_Word = (My_Number & 0xFFFF ) ;                     // Returns C000  

  return 0;
}
```

What I am not understanding is why I need to use 1FFFF to mask the High_Word.

I have tried different values to find what gets returned to find an explanation but something is not clicking and I don't like having anything that works without understanding why as that always leads to issues down the line.

Edit: Having read all the replies and done some re-thinking I have realised that rather than using 1FFFF I could have used FFFFUL to force it to an unsigned long integer and that works. Going further I can see that rather than shifting left to then shift right I could just use

High_Word = (My_Number >> 16);
Low_Word =  My_Number;

This code returns the expected values and I believe is more compliant.

Comment: i think because you want to shift something with a "width" of 1FFFF by 16 bits. So you need to account for that offset by "zeroing out" first.

Comment: Try it with `FFFF` instead of `1FFFF` - you should get the same result.

Comment: Presumably they  use `0x1FFFF << 16` because it's a 16-bit compiler, and this makes it shift a `long` not an `int`. Using `0xFFFF << 16` would shift a 16-bit value, which can't be shifted by 16 bits (it's UB) and isn't what the mask needs to be.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `0xFFFF << 16` is UB for the 16-bit `int`. And won't create a 32-bit mask either.

Comment: Not a 1FFFF explanation, yet an alternative with less issues: `High_Word = (My_Number >> 16) & 0xFFFF;`.

Comment: Even `High_Word = My_Number >> 16;` would work if it is certain that `High_Word` is 16 bits wide.

Comment: Try it with FFFF instead of 1FFFF - you should get the same result.                           The result is not the same, you get 0x0000

Answer (score 10):

The comments seem to indicate that `int` and `unsigned int` are 16 bits in the targeted C implementation, and that `long int` and `unsigned long int` are 32 bits.

In such a C implementation `0xFFFF` is an `unsigned int` per the table in C 2018 6.4.4.1 5. This means that `0xFFFF << 16` will take FFFF<sub>16</sub> as a 16-bit item and ask to shift it 16 bits. Then the behavior of the program is not defined because C 2018 6.5.7 3, about shifts, says:

> … If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

However, if we write `0x1FFFF`, this is too large for an `unsigned int`. Then the table tells us it is a `long int`, which is 32 bits.

Now `0x1FFFF << 16` attempts to shift a 32-bit item by 16 bits.

It may be the author of the code thought this code would have defined behavior, since it no longer falls afoul of the rule in 6.5.7 3.

Unfortunately, it does fall afoul of a different rule in 6.5.7 4:

> … If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In other words, while `0x1FFFF` is 32 bits, it is a signed type, and the signed type can only represent values up 7FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>. The mathematical product for the shift would be 1FFFF0000<sub>16</sub>, which does not fit. So the behavior is not defined.

Had the author written `0x1FFFFu` to request an unsigned type or `0xFFFFul` to request an `unsigned long int`, then the behavior would be defined. That is because, for shifting an unsigned operand, the result is defined even if the product is not representable: Excess bits are discarded (as specified in the C standard, the result is wrapped modulo a modulus for the type).

I conjecture that, in the targeted C implementation `0x1FFFF << 16` produces FFFF0000<sub>16</sub> in the bits of a `long int`, and that is why the author used that code. Even though the C standard does not define the behavior, it may work. In contrast, `0xFFFF << 16` likely produces only a 16-bit result, which cannot be correct since FFFF<sub>16</sub> is needed in the high bits.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am not understanding is why I need to use 1FFFF to mask the
> High_Word, I would have though the 16 bit shift left would have

This makes no sense and it may invoke undefined behaviour if `sizeof(int) <= 4`.

I believe that the original programmer simply hit `1` by mistake when typing the function. Another clue is that he was thinking about *signed* numbers not really understanding how they work. Maybe he wanted to enforce 32bit integer constant (if ints are 16bits long), but in this case this code invokes undefined behaviour;
Basically, do not take this code as anything good

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long My_Number;      
    unsigned int High_Word;        
    unsigned int Low_Word;            
    
    My_Number = 0x6000C000UL;     

    High_Word = My_Number >> 16;    
 
    Low_Word = My_Number & 0xFFFF;                    


    printf("%x %x\n", High_Word, Low_Word);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Eh45KqEMe

Comment: It's 16-bit integers as commented with `unsigned int High_Word;  // 16 bit`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I meant `<=`

Comment: See my earlier comment: they shifted `0x1FFFF < 16` because it is the 32-bit value needed for the mask. `0xFFFF < 16` is UB with a 16-bit `int` anyway, and would result in a 16-bit value still. Shifting an unsigned value to drop bits out of the top is not UB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid worrying about endianness (and possibly other issues, like binary encoding - 1's complement or 2's complement) and achieve true portability, use division:

```
High_Word = ( My_Number / 65536UL ) ;     // Returns 6000
Low_Word  = ( My_Number % 65536UL ) ;     // Returns C000
```

If the compiler is smart enough, it will choose the best way (fastest) to achieve those calculations, since 65536UL is a power of 2.

This method is especially safe, considering that your numbers are *unsigned*. For signed numbers, it might cause some problems - the subject of another question.

Comment: I had not thought of using division and modulus,  as you say it is powers of two and so a case of shifting so should be compiler efficient.  I am also only using unsigned numbers because these values are for timer and comparator registers that have High and Low 16 bit registers but I want to use a 32 bit value.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no endianness difference between using bit ops or arithmetic division.  Today both consume the same time aprox. But there was a time in which dividing was a very expensive (the most, apart of floating point) operation.  You can mask thinking in powers of two and polynomials, or arithmetic.  And both solutions are equally portable, if done correctly.

Comment: @spectric: I have met at least one processor in the past which literally did not have a shifting instruction. So the shifting written in C was actually implemented by other means. I did not use this processor myself, but one of my colleagues at a previous job, working for another project.

Comment: @LuisColorado: If we talk about the capabilities of the various processors, you might be more on the right side (and in the past, things were definitely as you describe). But here we have a C language situation, during times when compilers are quite smart at optimizations.

Comment: @spectric: While I do shifting operations myself, in situations like this the math operation is better because it splits a number into two numbers - exactly what you want. The shift-and-mask solution fits better (as a concept) if you want to extract the bits without caring about the actual value. The line is fine and blurry, but it is still there. I dare to make this statement because "My_Number" is a "counter value", not the random configuration bits of some exotic register.

Comment: @LuisColorado: the situation _would_ be more dangerous (and as a result I _would_ be more right) if OP would dereference a pointer. In that case endiannes could hurt more. In all my experience I used shifts and masks and I did not have a problem, but then again, I did not use very exotic processors, and portability was always not an issue - I never wrote a program which needed to run without modification (except recompilation) on two or more different architectures. As long as testing proves that things happen as intended, both ways are good.

Comment: Nope, endiannes has nothing to do on how bit ops operate, and also on how integer arithmetic is done.  That is an implementation issue, but C doesn't define different ways of work for the different possible implementations.  No endianness trouble is happening here.

Comment: bit 0 of an integer is always the LSB, and bit n the MSB.  Independent of the endianness of the architecture.  `signed` and `unsigned` integers implement `>>` and `<<` differently to make them to appear as _multiplication by a power of 2_  (this is mandatory by the C standards since the inception, appearing in the first edition of _The C programming language_ by K&R) so this is the nexus that joins together integer arithmetic with bitops arithmetic.  It is not my interpretation, but is stated so in the language definition.

Comment: The code shown will work exactly the same using big endian or low endian architecture.  Believe me, I have tested it on Sun sparc (big endian) hp-ux Pa-risc architecture (big endian) Intel/linux&BSD&SCO systems (little endian) and always works the same.

Comment: I had in mind the endianness of the bytes. MSByte on one architecture is the LSByte on another architecture. And that is where someone not paying enough attention (or being a beginner) could get into trouble. While I understand your level of experience, you also needs to understand that our answers here will also be read by beginners. And it is them we needs to us on. In practice the "I will do it because Luis also does it" is bad practice.

Comment: You seem not to understand how bit ops work.